# My UIlabel not updating and I would like for it to update the speed of a moving vehicle or bike etc?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I want to update integers for my uilabel for speed but it seems not working.Sorry for the basic question, but this bugs me for a while now.I created a mainviewcontroller.xib view and try to set my Uilabel, but they are not updating. My uilabel is called speedView

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CLController = [[CoreLocationController alloc] init];
    CLController.delegate = self;
    [CLController.locMgr startUpdatingLocation];

}
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {
    NSNumber *speedCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
    [speedView setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"number is %@d",speedCount]];
    }

- (void)locationError:(NSError *)error {
    speedView.text = [error description];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [CLController release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <LoginDelegate,WEPopoverParentView,PopoverControllerDelegate,MainMenuDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
    IBOutlet MKMapView *userMap;
    IBOutlet UILabel *speedView;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *speedView;
@property(nonatomic) int speedCount;
- (void)setSpeedView:(UILabel *)speedView;
```

Does anyone suggest for me an idea ? I thought.any ideas why the value is not coming through?

Comment: Have you verified that `locationUpdate:` is actually being called? If so, have you verified that `speedView` is not `nil`?

Comment: I just checked it is set to nil, what do i change it to?

Comment: If `speedView` is an `IBOutlet` make sure it is connected properly in IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely because you are not updating the speedCount variable. It is just at a standby phase. You need to do this:

```
// have number shown after being increased
speedCount++
```

This is going to bee needed before your

```
[speedView setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"number is %@d",speedCount]];
```

line

Hope this helps!

Comment: when i added that i receive this error Arithmetic on pointer to interface 'NSNumber', which is not a constant size for this architecture and platform

Comment: ok, well I see that you have an @property int at the bottom, so why do you also have an NSNumber as the same name? You can just use the int variable, do the speedCount++ as I showed above, and then all you gotta do is leave the [speedView setText:..]; line, but in your format, take out the @, it should be stringWithFormat:@"%d", speedCount];

Comment: int *speedCount = [int numberWithInt:1] ;speedCount++;
    [speedView setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@d",speedCount];  should it look like this?

Comment: int doesn't need a pointer. keep this line int *speedCount = [int numberWithInt:1] out...it should be speedCount = 0; speedCount++; [speedView setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", speedCount];

Comment: you don't have to create a new speedCount because you have your @property (nonatomic) int speedCount; so just set that value to be 0, or any other number, and then just make it constantly increase by saying speedCount++, and then to see the number, just do the setText method, and youre good to go

Comment: Ok so i took the line off and now i get this error  Use of undeclared identifier 'speedCount'

Comment: what do you think could be the problem?

Comment: type @synthesize speedCount; underneath your implementation line that displays the class name in the .m file

Comment: no matter the case, every time you create a property in your interface (.h), you MUST use synthesize *propertyName*; in your implementation file. So, go ahead and do @synthesize for both speedView, and speedCount